# MySql multiple columns as primary key doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I create the MySql table by the following sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `agent` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `app` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app`,`agent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you see, the field 'app' and 'agent' is the primary key. But unfortunately it doesn't work when I insert the following data, it always show the duplicated key in 'app' field:

```
app     agent       name
-------------------------
MyApp    ios         cde
MyApp    android     abc
```

Can anybody tell me anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: You are able to insert those 2 records?

Comment: No, I can only insert the first row. I got the error message when I'm trying to insert the second record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your primary key `app` and `agent` are a primary key **together**, not two individual keys.

You'll be able to add many rows with app = 'MyApp' as long as agent differs. And the other way around.

If you wan't to disallow multiple rows with the same app and multiple rows with the same agent add normal unique indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `agent` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `app` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE app_index (`app`),
  UNIQUE agent_index (`agent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough. What I want is to allow to insert the same app with different agent. That's why I'm using the app and agent as primary key together. But it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The set of primary keys in MySQL does not check for individual unique values, it will give duplicate error when you will try to insert same set of values in multiple records, but both the columns will not accept NULL values

Eg.

```
app     agent       name
-------------------------
MyApp    ios         cde
MyApp    ios         abc        - it will give you error as "Duplicate entry 'MyApp-ios' for key 'PRIMARY'"
```

may this will help you